# Trouble starting nodeos - multiple errors

Tags: nodeos

I'm working off of this:

https://developers.eos.io/welcome/latest/getting-started/development-environment/start-your-node-setup

1.1: keosd starts correctly.

1.2: after I enter the nodeos commands I get the following:

> [2]  + exit 254   nodeos -e -p eosio --plugin eosio::producer_plugin
> --plugin  --plugin

I'm unsure if that's expected or an error message.

2.1: i get the following after I run $ tail -f nodeos.log

> std::exception::what: Unknown option 'bnet-follow-irreversible' inside
> the config file /Users/wilfra/Library/Application
> Support/eosio/nodeos/config/config.ini
>
> error 2020-10-22T12:28:00.847 thread-0  main.cpp:131
> main                 ]
> /Users/anka/eos/libraries/appbase/application.cpp(298): Throw in
> function bool appbase::application::initialize_impl(int, char **,
> vector<appbase::abstract_plugin *>) Dynamic exception type:
> boost::wrapexceptstd::runtime_error std::exception::what: Unknown
> option 'bnet-follow-irreversible' inside the config file
> /Users/wilfra/Library/Application Support/eosio/nodeos/config/config.ini
>
> error 2020-10-22T12:35:50.406 thread-0  main.cpp:131
> main                 ]
> /Users/anka/eos/libraries/appbase/application.cpp(298): Throw in
> function bool appbase::application::initialize_impl(int, char **,
> vector<appbase::abstract_plugin *>) Dynamic exception type:
> boost::wrapexceptstd::runtime_error std::exception::what: Unknown
> option 'bnet-endpoint' inside the config file
> /Users/wilfra/Library/Application Support/eosio/nodeos/config/config.ini

I'm not sure what other information is needed here. I'm on MacOS and just upgraded to the latest version of EOSIO via Brew.

Thanks for any help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was given a solution by conr2d on Telegram.

The problem was I had an old config.ini file. I deleted it and ran the nodeos commands again and it solved these errors. Running nodeos generates a new config.ini if one does not exist.

File is in: ~/Library/Application\ Support/eosio/nodeos/data

Answer (score 0):

The key to the problem is this part of the error message:

```
std::exception::what: Unknown option 'bnet-follow-irreversible' inside the config file /Users/wilfra/Library/Application Support/eosio/nodeos/config/config.ini
```

It tells you that you have an option in your config.ini file that is no longer valid, and removing it would fix the problem (or at least reveal the next option in your config file that wasn't supported)